# Cloud Foundry EC2 Minimal Setup

Tags: web-services, cloud-foundry

I know we can install cloud foundry on local machine, but I want to install cloud foundry on a server eg. EC2 box.
Apparently, AWS uses 'Xen' as a virtual machine setup over which I cannot install Virtual-Box.
So, what round about should I take to install cloud foundry on a server using one or two boxes ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are instructions for installing Bosh Lite on AWS.  It's a similar process to installing it on a local VM.  You can then use Bosh to deploy CF to your bosh-lite VM.  See more here.

https://github.com/cloudfoundry/bosh-lite/blob/master/docs/aws-provider.md

That would give you a straightforward way to get a CF installation running on AWS.  It's going to be a single VM setup though, so it's not something you'd want to use for production.

I'm suggesting this because you seem to have some experience deploying CF locally, so this should be a huge jump in difficulty.  It will also give you a small / minimal setup that shouldn't cost an arm and a leg.

If you want an HA production setup, these are not the instructions for you.  You should instead look at the docs here.

https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/deploying/aws/index.html

Hope that helps!

Comment: This is very helpful! Thanks @Daniel.